# Reading words until EOF

Tags: c, scanf, eof, words

I'm trying to make a program that reads words until the EOF, and then does something with those words. It doesn't matter what it does for now so let's just say it prints them right back. So this is what it should look like in console:

these are some words[then here I hit the EOF key]

these

are

some

words

This is the way I've tried it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 21

int r_word(char s[]){
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!=' '){
    s[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}

int main(){
  char word[MAX];
  int d;

  while((d = r_word(word))>0){
    printf("%s\n", word);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

So my idea was that the r_word function stores a word in the string 's' character by character so that it could check for the EOF. 
But, unlike my expectations, this is what it looks like when I run this:

these are some words [EOF]

these

are

some [and then it stops here, still in the loop i guess]
[hit EOF again]

words

So no matter how many words I type it prints out all of them except for the last one, then the program just hangs there until I hit EOF again when it prints out the last word. 
Any ideas?

P.S. This is a school example in which we are not allowed to use any advanced scanning methods such as fscanf or whatever. Only the basic functions are allowed.

Comment: `char c` --> `int c` and inputting EOF means `ctrd+d/w` and `Enter`

Comment: What happens if a word is longer than `MAX`?

Comment: I still haven't gotten to handling that case, but I don't think it's relevant for now

Comment: Have you made the changes I said?

Comment: @koy - You should learn to consider it in the first place. Coders that forget these things just leave the bug in - and it bites them in the future

Comment: #coderredoc Still the same after change to int

Comment: 1) Hitting "EOF" is odd - I would not expect an EOF key.  What key(s),key-combinations did you really enter?  2) "except for the last one, then the program just hangs there until I hit EOF again" is confusing.  How do you indicate a "word" is the **last** one?  Research how to indicate end-of-file.  I am confident the key strokes you enter are not as needed. 3) Change to `printf("<%s>\n", word);` to better see what `word` is as it may contain line-feed and other unexpected characters.

Comment: I suspect what you are getting is the the first `[hit the EOF key]` only flushes the keyboard into `stdin` and an immediate following 2nd `[hit the EOF key]` forms the true end-of-file signal.  For a cheat, end with <space><eof><eof>

Comment: The important question is: must `[EOF]` immediately follow the `s` in `"words"` or may an  space/line-feed get interjected between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Adding "space" "EOF", instead of just "EOF", to the last word should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below. Instead of 'EOF' I used '\n', followed by a little trick to handle the spaces. I hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 32

void handleWords()
{
    int i = 0;
    char input, word[MAX];
    while((input = (char) getchar()) != '\n' && i < MAX-1)
    {
        if(input == ' ') input = '\n';
        word[i++] = input;
    }
    word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", word);
}

int main()
{
    handleWords();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> then the program just hangs there until I hit EOF again when it prints out the last word

OP first "[hit the EOF key]" only flushes the keyboard buffer into `stdin`.

At that point, `stdin` has `"these are some words"` and code processes that which will print out:

```
these<line feed>
are<line feed>
some<line feed>
```

The `"words"` have been fully read by `fgetc()`, yet `r_word()` is still waiitng for something after the `'s'`.

OP 2nd "[hit the EOF key]" signals an end-of-file and so `(c=getchar())` received an `EOF` and the final output occurs.

```
words<line feed>
```

---

To remedy, find if the interface allows for a single keyboard event that signals end-of-file  or [append a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213294/reading-words-until-eof/48214523#comment83410485_48213294).

Alternatively do not print until a line of input is complete.